# argfile: read/write stdio or specified file depending on command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

A unix convention is to use `-` as a placeholder for stdin/stdout in command lines, e.g. `gcc -x c -` to compile stdin as C. I often find myself writing logic to get this behavior in my Python scripts, so I abstracted it out into a context manager:

```py
from typing import IO

class argfile:
    def __init__(self, default: IO, filename: str, mode: str = 'r'):
        self.__file = default if filename == '-' else open(filename, mode)
        self.__should_close = filename != '-'

    def __enter__(self) -> IO:
        return self.__file

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.close()

    def close(self):
        if self.__should_close:
            self.__file.close()
```

Now instead of writing this mess:

```py
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.inputfile == '-':
    infile = sys.stdin
else:
    infile = open(args.inputfile, 'r')

if args.output == '-':
    outfile = sys.stdout
else:
    outfile = open(args.output, 'w')

try:
    do_work(infile, outfile)
finally:
    if args.output != '-':
        outfile.close()
    if args.inputfile != '-':
        infile.close()
```

I instead write:

```py
args = parser.parse_args()

with argfile(sys.stdin, args.inputfile, 'r') as infile, \
        argfile(sys.stdout, args.output, 'w') as outfile:
    do_work(infile, outfile)
```

I do consider it important to close the files and not close stdin/stdout, as I often call the `main()` functions of my Python scripts inside other scripts with much longer lifetimes. Also note that I named the class in lowercase because I think of it more as a function call replacing `open(...)` than as a class constructor.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use [`type=argparse.FileType("r")`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/argparse.html#argparse.FileType) to get automatic handling of '-' as a command line argument?

Comment: @RootTwo Because I didn't know that exists. This is exactly why I asked this question: I wanted someone to tell me I was working too hard. Although I don't quite see how to close the file without closing `stdin`/`stdout` if a `-` was passed...

Comment: @RootTwo I'm not going to use that, though, see https://bugs.python.org/issue13824 . In particular, "FileType is not what you want for anything but quick scripts that can afford to either leave a file open or to close stdin and/or stdout." I don't want to do either of those things. However, that thread does have some other solutions I might prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be simplified using the `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def argfile(default: IO, filename: str, mode: str = 'r'):
    file_like = open(filename, mode) if filename != '-' else default
    yield file_like
    if filename != '-':
        file_like.close()
```

Use it the same way as your code.

Is `default` ever anything other than `stdin` or `stdout`? If not, then maybe something like:

```
@contextmanager
def argfile(filename: str, mode: str = 'r'):

    if filename != '-' :
        file_like = open(filename, mode)

    else:
        file_like = sys.stdin if mode == 'r' else sys.stdout

    yield file_like

    if filename != '-':
        file_like.close()
```

Comment: I ended up using a modification of the second version which is `if filename == '-': yield sys.stdout if mode == 'w' else sys.stdin; else: with open(...) as f: yield f`, which is a bit shorter and nicer IMO